# In ElasticSearch, use 'match' to match a field of type keyword and 'term' to match a field of text type. What does ES do?

Tags: java

```
# Create a DSL statement for the index library
PUT /mytest
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "someText1": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "someText2": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}

# Add a piece of data
POST /mytest/_doc/1
{
  "someText1": "Hello World",
  "someText2": "Hello World"
}

# Use 'term' to match a field of type text, and the query result is empty
GET /mytest/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "someText1": "Hello World"
    }
  }
}

# Use 'match' to match a field of type keyword. The query result has the above data
GET /mytest/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "someText2": "Hello World"
    }
  }
}
```

**May I ask how ES will execute these two queries?**

I would have thought that if I used 'match' to match a field of type keyword, match would use a 'standard' word divider to split the input, then match the keyword's inverted index, and the result set would be empty.

Comment: Are you asking what the result of those queries is? Why don't you just try it?

Answer (score 0):

In elasticsearch:

- **Term** is an exact query
- **Match** is a query passed through a text analyzer.

To explain in over-simplified terms:

So term queries will only match "Hello World" and NOT "hello world", "HELLO world", "HeLLo WoRlD" etc. However match queries will match all of those and with fuzziness can match even misspelt or similar words.

Note: Elastic search adds a warning called
`Avoid using the term query for text fields.`

Thumb rule is use term queries for exact matches like say a tag, or an email id etc.

So for your example use the term query on the keyword type of field which is someText2.

---

Further Reading:

- [Term Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html)
- [Match Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html)